# Some Materials are greyed out in inpector

Tags: urp, shader-graph

Im using Unity and I have several shader graphs in my project. Although all of the objects in my scene each have a assigned material I find that there are several materials which can be edited in the inspector and several that can not! Is there a particular reason why this happens?

ps. Some of the shader graphs have exposed parameters in the blackboard
The project uses the Universal Render Pipeline

[The inspector looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4UuD.png)